# When will the CanExcute event be raised by the CommandSource

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls, routed-commands, commandbinding

When will the **CanExecute** event be ideally raised by the control that realizes the **ICommandSource** interface? I tried to add a breakpoint to the handler to check when it is getting raised and it seems to be executed whenever the control is rendered on the screen. *Can someone explain when exactly it will be raised and how to raise it at will?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()** is the only possible way. Check these links for more details,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b66a2fda-4e66-47fd-9b1f-1a1be1ce30bf

http://robburke.net/2008/04/23/wpf-command-pattern-when-does-it-query-canexecute/comment-page-1/